# php date comparison issue, i try many date and it doesn't work at all

Tags: php, date

My code is working well as below

```
$sql = "SELECT Type, dt, SUM(Amount) AS Total FROM Expense GROUP BY Type";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Type</th><th>Amount</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "</td><td>".$row["Type"]."</td><td>". round($row[Total],2)."</td></tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

[image]

but I add WHERE dt BETWEEN '2020-01-23' AND '2020-03-01' into it as below, it shows 0 result. 
Please help to solve this issue.

```php
<?php

$sql = "SELECT Type, dt, SUM(Amount) AS Total FROM Expense GROUP BY Type  WHERE dt BETWEEN '2020-01-23' AND '2020-03-01' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Type</th><th>Amount</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "</td><td>".$row["Type"]."</td><td>". round($row[Total], 2)."</td></tr>";
    }


} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: what type is `dt` ? and what data do you actually have that you expected the query to match, but didn't match?

Comment: Does all the PHP code play any role in the issue? In other words, does the query return the expected rows in the first place?

Comment: dt is a date.
the query return the expected rows in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your group by clause is in the wrong location, see below, it has to follow the where clause

```
$sql = "SELECT Type, dt, SUM(Amount) AS Total FROM Expense WHERE dt BETWEEN '2020-01-23' AND '2020-03-01' GROUP BY Type  ";
```

Comment: @EricChong When I asked if the query was returning the expected rows (in order to determine if it was a PHP issue) you confirmed it was. How could it possibly be the case if the SQL code was invalid to begin with??